# Pre-authorize application in Azure Active Directory: hide scope from other applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-authentication

I have an Azure Active Directory first-party-application X, and I want to authenticate requests from another first-party-application Y. In order to do that, I want to use pre-authorization.

So I added a new scope Z, and pre-authorized client with application id Y, and permission Z.

I noticed that any third-party-application can choose its permissions. I want to prevent any third-party-application to use the new scope I have added.

How can I prevent third-party-application from choosing a certain scope as a permission?

Thanks!

Comment: that really only concerns you if your application is published as multi-tenant. Because only in that construct you will have "3rd party" apps who will be able to see your and request access to it. There is no really a way today to do so. Do you really build a multi-tenant application that needs special permissions for "internal" use only, or it is something else? Because, if inside an organisation only you have much stronger control - you may designate only specific users/group to be able to access that app.

Comment: on another note, if you want to pre-authorize only single applicaiton, you can easily check the application id in comming access_token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens -> `appid` resp. `azp` claim). Know that app_id is "special" and thread it "specially". Not ideal, but a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your scope Z you can choose to only let admins consent other applications of using it.

But that still delegates access control to others than the ones responsible for the scope Z in application X. To get full control of who can get an access token for your application Y you need to turn on User Assignment Required in the corresponding Enterprise Application, and add the users and groups that should be able to get a token.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There is no way to hide permissions, or publish permissions only to specific client. This should only be a concern if you are developing a [multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/setup-multi-tenant-app) and not single-tenant one.

If you still have a concerns, the only option I see is to hard code the `Application ID` of the "specially pre-authorized" application. And make authorization decision based on the `appid` respective `azp` [claim in the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens).